# Using dynamically generated data with keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm training a neural network using keras but I'm not sure how to feed the training data into the model in the way that I want.

My training data set is effectively infinite, I have some code to generate training examples as needed, so I just want to pipe a continuous stream of novel data into the network. keras seems to want me to specify my entire dataset in advance by creating a numpy array with everything in it, but this obviously wont work with my approach.

I've experimented with creating a generator class based on `keras.utils.Sequence` which seems like a better fit, but it still requires me to specify a length via the `__len__` method which makes me think it will only create that many examples before recycling them. Can someone suggest a better approach?

Comment: Please add more descripton about your data? How it's generated? How it should be loaded towards the model?

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for [from_generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator).

Comment: @xdurch0 that looks like what I need thanks. If you want to create an answer I will upvote/accept